# javascript speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, delay

On an average system, say

```
Processor: Core 2 Duo 2.2 GHz, Memory: 4 GB
```

How much DOM-manipulations can javascript make?
Is there a way to see how long (in milliseconds) a simple jQuery action takes? For example one like:

```
$("#example").css("color","red");
```

Comment: Totally depends which browser you are talking about - massive massive differences in JavaScript performance in different browsers and versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're browser supports it, you could use `console.profile();` before the call(s) and `console.profileEnd();` after. You console should show you output how long it took, the number of calls, etc.

```
console.profile();
$("#example").css("color","red");
console.profileEnd();
```

Nettuts+ has a tutorial [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-jquery-beginners-can-test-and-improve-their-code/).

Answer (score 3):

The process of making these determinations is called "profiling." You can find profilers built into the Chrome Developer Tools, and Firebug for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

```
var start = Date.now();

for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { // any number of repetitions
    $("#example").css("color", "red");
}

var end = Date.now();
alert("It took " + Math.round((end - start) / 10000).toString() + " milliseconds on average.");
```

is how you'd time it. I don't know about DOM actions. You can look in the `sizzle.js` source to find out exactly what it does, though I know it optimizes for ID selectors and then it depends on the browser. Maybe they traverse the tree in order until they find a matching id. It would be pretty fast.

Comment: You would never time just one.

Comment: I'm personally a fan of using Date.now(), since you don't have to go through the hassle of creating a new object that'll get GC'd. To be fair, it's like a 5% speedup at best, but these things add up.

Also, you don't need to call .toString() -- automatic coercion!

Comment: @Steve: I always use `.toString()`, just in case. It can help to remeber that `"Hello " + 15 - 6 + " world"` isn't right. Besides, does it matter? :)

Comment: In those cases, just use parentheses! But no, it doesn't actually matter.